# Azure Pipeline App Service Deploy: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/bin/python'

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that runs some tests and deploys to Azure AppService after a commit to master. The tests complete fine however the run fails when deploying the app to the Azure App Service and returns the error below.

I am using the built-in Azure App Service Deploy task and not writing my own YAML so I am unsure what could be causing this error.

.YAML

```
steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.7'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'

- script: |
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    python manage.py test
  displayName: 'Running tests and migrations'
  env:
    DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: $(DJANGO_SECRET_KEY)

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'Subscription(ae713e97-5a9d-1e62-80c5-57ab16d6eeaa)'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'methodportal-staging'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.7'
```

Error

```
Starting: AzureRmWebAppDeployment
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure App Service deploy
Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
Version      : 4.198.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
==============================================================================
[error]Error: Failed find: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/bin/python'
Finishing: AzureRmWebAppDeployment
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to specify an artifact (*.zip) to deploy. The following is the default template to build and deploy Python app to Linux Web App on Azure for your reference.

```
variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureServiceConnectionId: '45560d44-3c74-4ea9-8dbb-a936c9048106'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'weblinux'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'weblinux'

  # Project root folder. Point to the folder containing manage.py file.
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  # Python version: 3.7
  pythonVersion: '3.7'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : weblinux'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

In your scenario, you can try to archive file as zip and then try to deploy it.  Please make sure the file path is correct.